# Can I use a @State for multiple View element ? [SwiftUI]

Tags: swiftui, state

Let say I have a list of Component() and I want to be able to drag each of them individually. So I have declare a

```
@State var cardPosition = CGSize.zero
```

and as a modifier for my Component() :

```
.offset(x: self.cardPosition.width, y: self.cardPosition.height) .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged { 
value in self.cardPosition = value.translation }
```

The problem I have is that if I copy this modifier on all my Component(), if I drag one of them I drag all of them...
How can I change the position of the only card I drag without having to create a single @State for each of them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no way. one variable can hold one value. you can use collection  wrapped with '@State' property wrapper. '@State' var carPositions: [CGSize] = .....

Comment: So no way to like assign the @State var to only the focused item ?

I have to create an array ?

Comment: yes, the information about "selected" or "focused" card is usable to access the right element in you positions collection

Comment: ok, I'll try that, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently managed state on multiple views using a Dictionary, but I don't know the "best practice" way to achieve this. It likely will involve using some sort of collection though, so this should be a good start.

```swift
@State var showDetails: [Date: Bool] = [:]
```

Then in my init, I create the dictionary from dates that are relevant to the views and use that to give the State collection its initial value

```swift
let detailDays = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
                                days.map { ($0, false) })
    
self._showDetails = State<[Date: Bool]>(initialValue: detailDays)
```

Then later I'm using the collection to toggle state on the appropriate view

```swift
MyView()
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
    showDetails[date]!.toggle()
})
```

```swift
DayDetailView(date: day,
              logs: logs[day] ?? [],
              closeAction: {
                showDetails[day]!.toggle()
              },
...
```